# Single or shared database (ORACLE) for several microservices (whith use of Liquibase)

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase, jhipster, microservices

(microservices generated with jhipster based on spring-Boot/Data/Cloud and Liquibase)

I have three different microservices (MS) based on spring-boot and generated with JHIPSTER.

These MS must use the same Oracle database (and I use Liquibase for DB versionning).

The solution I have found is to create all tables of my 3 MS when I launch the first MS.

I copied all liquibase configuration files like /src/main/resources/config/liquibase/changelog/20160708140936_added_entity_XXXXXX.xml in the first started MS configuration folder.

is there other (clean and better) solutions ?

thanks

Comment: So you are creating the same set of tables three times , one for each service?

Comment: Hi @Ismail Hawayel,  Initially, each MicroService created its own tables.
but with the workaround I created all the tables in the first service that I run (currently it is the Microservice Gateway)

Comment: Initallay each microservice has her databases; example: for microservice MS_A, i create tables (T_A_1, T_A_2, T_A_3) which has his own DATABASE DB_A, for MS_B, i create tables T_B_1, T_B_2, T_B_3, T_B_4 with  DATABASE DB_B. After the workaround, i create all tables when i launch MS_A in single DATABASE DB_Shared.

Comment: You can run liquibase outside of your application and use eg. maven liquibase plugin to migrate database. Then keep db changelog as separate subproject/repo. Anyway, having the same database for three microservices looks like having all monolith and microservice disadvantages in one solution.

Comment: Thank's for all